# Loop along a line in tikz-feynman

Tags: tikz-feynman

In tikz-feynman, I want to draw a curved arc between two points, and then attach a loop to this. Here is an extremely hack version I did as a stopgap:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}

    \vertex (t) at (0,2);
    \vertex (b) at (0,-2);
    \vertex (lt) at (-0.5,1);
    \vertex (lm) at (-1,0);
    \vertex (lb) at (-0.5,-1);
    \vertex (rt) at (0.5,1);
    \vertex (rm) at (1,0);
    \vertex (rb) at (0.5,-1);
    \diagram*{
    (t) -- (lt) -- (lm) -- (lb) -- (b),
    (t) -- (rt) -- (rm) -- (rb) -- (b),
    (lt) -- [gluon] (lb),
    };  
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: diagram]

I hope the idea is clear enough. This would be adequate for my purposes except that I want the lines to be curved, i.e. this should be two arcs between (t) and (b), not this ugly diamond-shaped thing. I think what I want to do is just draw the two arcs from (t) to (b) and then define some vertices "along the arcs" with which I can make the gluon line, but have struggled to figure out how to do this.

Because this diagram is part of a larger equation of diagrams, I would prefer to use absolute vertex positions for at least (t) and (b).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Flexible answer. You can change the position at will by adjusting `.3` and `.7` to your needs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[postaction={decorate,
decoration={markings,mark=at position .3 with {\coordinate (lt);},
mark=at position .7 with {\coordinate (lb);}}}] (0,0) circle (2); 
\begin{feynman}
    \diagram*{
    (lt) -- [gluon] (lb),
    };  
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**: (Just in case someone wants to do this within a `diagram` of tikz-feynman. You can work with `quarter right`. Then some of your vertices become unnecessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}

    \vertex (lt) at (-0.5,1);
    \vertex (lb) at (-0.5,-1);
    \vertex (rt) at (0.5,1);
    \vertex (rb) at (0.5,-1);
    \diagram*{
    (lt) --[quarter right]  (lb) --[quarter right] (rb)
    -- [quarter right] (rt) -- [quarter right] (lt),
    (lt) -- [gluon] (lb),
    };  
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's an interesting workaround--thanks! I would still kind of like to know if there's a solution where I can place nodes along my lines, so I could have more control over the shape of the lines... this solution also has the difficulty that I can't control where exactly the top and bottom of the diagram are, which will make it hard to align this diagram wrt other diagrams in an equation.

Comment: @twoform Of course there are plenty of such possibilities in Ti*k*Z. The question is whether you insist on a pure tikz-feynman solution.

Comment: I am fully willing to use a non tikz-feynman solution! I suppose that might be the way to go at this point. I imagine putting this all together in just standard tikz might be easier. Too bad though, I am lazy and like tikz-feynman ;)

Comment: @twoform I added an alternative.