# Feynman Diagrams inside circles

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, coordinates, tikz-feynman, tikz-positioning

I'm trying to use `tikz-feynman` to draw Feynman diagrams encased in circles. I need the entire diagram to be inside a circle, with the lines touching the circle. This is necessary because these are diagrams for the Wilson loop operators in a Chern-Simons theory - see examples from Professor Bar-Natan's thesis below:
[image]
This example uses ellipses, which also suffice for me, but circles are easier and preferable.

Right now I am trying to draw the circle in tikz-feynman itself, by drawing solid lines for the circle arcs. Options like `half left` and `quarter left` allowed me to draw the circle's arcs easily for diagrams C and D. (My attempts are below.) But for something like diagram E, I cannot figure out how to force the triple vertex to be inside the circle. I tried using coordinate calculations to force the vertices to be at certain positions, and use the `out`,`in` keys to hardcode the lines to follow circular arcs, but my commands are simply overridden if I get too specific.

I am compiling with `Lualatex`. I have tried compiling with `pdflatex` but that only makes it worse.

Any advice on how to manipulate tikz-feynman to get what I want is appreciated.

If the only way is to draw a circle in tikz and then use tikz-feynman for the rest, how do I position the Feynman diagram vertices to lie on the circle?

My successful code for diagrams C, D:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \feynmandiagram [scale = 1, horizontal=a to b] {
    a -- [quarter left] b -- [quarter left] c -- [quarter left] d -- [quarter left] a,
    a -- [scalar] b,
    c -- [scalar] d
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \feynmandiagram [scale = 0.98, horizontal=a to b] {
    a -- [quarter left] b -- [quarter left] c -- [quarter left] d -- [quarter left] a,
    a -- [scalar] c,
    b -- [scalar] d
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And my various attempts at drawing E:
First, with no positioning,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \feynmandiagram [scale = 1, horizontal=a to b] {
    a --  b -- c -- a,
    a -- [scalar] d,
    b -- [scalar] d,
    c -- [scalar] d
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Then, I tried positioning everything explicitly.
**Edit**: The code below is somewhat incorrect since I have given the angles relative to the line connecting the vertices. According to the documentation, the flag for this should be true by default, but it seems to be false. Below, I have given an example with relative angles on, but the result is still disappointing.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
      \vertex (a);
      \vertex[right=of a] (d);
      \vertex (b) at ($(a)!1.73!30:(d)$);
      \vertex (c) at ($(a)!1.73!-30:(d)$);
      \diagram { a --  [out=30, in=30] b -- [out=30, in=30] c -- [out=30, in=30] a,
      a -- [scalar,out=0,in=0] d,
      b -- [scalar,out=0,in=0] d,
      c -- [scalar,out=0,in=0] d
        };
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

For comparison, compiling without `Lualatex`:
[image]

With the flag `relative=true`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
        \vertex (a);
        \vertex[above right= of a] (b);
        \vertex[below right= of a] (c);
        \vertex[right= of a] (d);
        a [particle=a] --[out=30, in = 150, relative=true] b[particle =b] ,
        b -- [out = 30, in = 150, relative = true] c [particle =c],
        c -- [out = 30, in = 150, relative = true] a,
        a -- [scalar] d [particle = d],
        b -- [scalar] d,
        c -- [scalar] d
        };
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Finally, I tried relying on `half left` and `quarter left`, but vertex d refuses to stay inside the circle:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
        \vertex (a);
        \vertex (b);
        \vertex (c);
        \vertex (d) at ($(a)!0.5!(b)$);      
        \diagram { a[particle = a] --  [half right] b[particle = b] -- [quarter right] c [particle =  c]-- [quarter right] a,
         d -- [scalar] b,
         d -- [scalar] c,
         d -- [scalar] a 
        };         
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

---

**Update:** I have made some progress using the `spring electrical layout`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{feynman}
        \vertex (a);
        \vertex[above= of a] (b);
        \vertex[below= of a] (c);
        \vertex[right= of a] (d);
        \diagram [spring electrical layout] {
        a [particle=a] --[out=60, in = 120, relative=true] b[particle =b] ,
        b -- [out = 60, in = 120, relative = true] c [particle =c ],
        c -- [out = 60, in = 120, relative = true] a,
        % b-- c [particle =c ],
        a -- [scalar] d [particle = d, electric charge=15],
        b -- [scalar] d,
        c -- [scalar] d
        };
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome. // Please add at least to your first code example: a) beginning at `\documentclass`, b) relevant packages etc., c) end with `\end{document}`, so we can copy compile and improve instad of guessing around ;-) Thank you // BTW, do you compile via Lualatex? // BTW: From your posted code it's obscure how you introduce e.g. circular shapes. What's about ellipses? Do you need them?

Comment: Hi, sure, I'll make those edits. 
I am compiling with Lualatex, yes.
Ellipses would also work for me, I prefer circles.

Comment: More or less unrelated: Do not place `\feynmandiagram` inside a `tikzpicture`, because this way you'll nest tikzpictures which is strongly discouraged. Either use a `feynman` environment inside a `tikzpicture` environment or use `\feynmandiagram` directly without a surrounding `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: The drawings you show are probably easer to create with pure Ti*k*Z. Is there a reason why you need to use the `tikz-feynman` package for this? One of the packages features is exactly positioning nodes automatically what you might not want here.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thanks for the advice, I'm a little new to tikz.
`tikz-feynman` would allow me to extend these diagrams to different line styles with arrows and label the particles with momenta and such, so I was preferring it. I'm not sure how much effort it would be to recreate it all in `tikz`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the answer to [Loop along a line in tikz-feynman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427947/loop-along-a-line-in-tikz-feynman), I think I have figured out the best way to approach this problem: draw a circle, decorate it with coordinates as markings, and then use `tikz-feynman` to connect them in whatever way you prefer.

Note that this compiles without `lualatex` - alternatively, use `\diagram*` to ensure this particular diagram does not use automatic placement.

It's also important to keep in mind that when using coordinates, vertices or nodes defined outside `\diagram` inside `\diagram*` with manual placement, use `(a)` instead of `a`, else `tikz` sometimes treats it as a different vertex. But this also does not work when using automatic placement, `lualatex` complains when you use `(a)`. If anyone understands this issue in more detail, I would be grateful for an explanation.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
    \draw[postaction={decorate,
decoration={markings,
        mark=at position .17 with {\coordinate (b);},
        mark=at position .5 with {\coordinate (a);},
        mark=at position .83 with {\coordinate (c);}
        }}] (0,0) circle (2); 
    
    \vertex[right=2cm of a] (d);

    \diagram*{
    (a)-- [scalar] (d),
    (b)-- [scalar] (d),
    (c)-- [scalar] (d),
    };
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]